# removing a column from a delimited file

Tags: perl, unix

I am trying to cut and paste together a tab-delimited file and have been using the cut and paste utilities from unix in this manner:

```
cut -f 1-66 file1 > file1a
cut -f 68- file1  > file1b
paste file1a file1b
```

However I was wondering if there was a way to do it in Perl/Ruby using the -F command because that probably would be quicker in the long run. For example

```
perl -F/\\t/ -ane
for every line in document
  for i (0..66) and (67..Last field in line)
    print $[i]
   end
   print \n
end
```

Comment: are you saying `cut` rewrites the output from its input file? Also, performance wise, assuming a multi-processor environment, 2 parrallel cuts feeding paste via a pipe should be very fast. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl could work this way:

```
perl -F/\\t/ -ane  'print join("\t", @F[0..66,68..$#F])'
```

`@F` contains parts of the string, `$#F` contains index of last element in `@F`

Answer (score 4):

Your original code seems to be missing some redirections.

How about:

```
cut -f1-66,68- input > output
```

I think it's unlikely that perl or ruby will be any faster than this.

Comment: True, `cut` is faster. "real    0m0.002s" for cut and "real    0m0.001s" for Perl

Comment: @sputnick Be careful with benchmarks like that. The biggest bottleneck is probably reading from the disk. The first run will probably get most of the file into buffers, the second will not have to access disk.